# Identifying Leads for which Accounts already exist (without a conversion relationship)

Tags: soql, account, leads, findduplicates

It happens that Leads are created, for which an Account already exists. How can I identify these Leads?

The combination of Name and Postalcode is sufficiently identifying a match for us.

What I tried: I created custom formula fields on Lead and Account 'Name+Postalcode' and I tried this SOQL query:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Lead
WHERE Status != 'Converted' AND
PostalCode != '' AND
Name_PostalCode__c IN (
  SELECT Name_PostalCode__c FROM Account
)
```

But this produces the error:

> semi join sub selects can only query id fields

Obviously id fields will not work, because this involves different kinds of objects.

What is another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it depending on your requirements. I assume you want to do it only once(and not after insert of each lead). You can try a simple apex script, for example:

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Name_PostalCode__c FROM Account];
Set<String> npcs = new Set<String>();
for (Account a : accs) {
    npcs.add(a.Name_PostalCode__c);
}
List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id
FROM Lead
WHERE Status != 'Converted' AND
PostalCode != '' AND
Name_PostalCode__c IN :npcs];
```

If it takes too long or throws an error about your query being too long, you can also extract both Accounts and Leads, put them in an excel file and use a simple VLOOKUP to find matching Accounts.

In case you want to do that on regular basis, think about creating a new lookup field from lead to account and an apex batch to initially fill in all the lookups. It would select all leads in it's `start()` method and in the `execute()` you would query accounts based on the Name_PostalCode__c and try to match them to a lead. Then, update leads. Also, do the same logic on insert and update of the leads, so your data will be up-to-date. When this is all up-and-running, you will simply need to query based on that new lookup field:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Lead
WHERE Status != 'Converted' AND
PostalCode != '' AND
Matched_Account__c != null
```

Comment: Thank you! I especially like your second suggestion. Making the lookup field, filling it via a trigger (or flow) and putting it on the Lead page layout, would enable the users to immediately recognize duplicate leads (duplicate in the sense of: a matching Account might already exist).